# What is the difference between declare datatable class with () and without ()

Tags: vb.net

I have a question about declaring a datatable variable.

Is there any difference if I declared a datatable variable as:

```
Dim xDt as new datatable
```

or

```
Dim xDt as new datatable()
```

??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you're not declaring a class there. You are declaring a variable of type `DataTable`. The declaration is irrelevant anyway. What matters is that you are creating an instance of the `DataTable` class by invoking a constructor with the `New` keyword. A constructor is just a special method and, in VB, you can omit the parentheses when calling a method without arguments. This:

```vb
Dim table As New DataTable
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```vb
Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable
```

which is functionally equivalent to this:

```vb
Dim table As DataTable

table = New DataTable
```

As you can see there, the last line is what matters and the variable declaration is irrelevant. That last line is equivalent to this:

```vb
table = New DataTable()
```

Whether you include the parentheses or not is up to you but I would suggest that you pick an option for a logical reason and stick to it consistently.

Personally, I always include parentheses on standard method calls but I always omit them from constructors. I do the former to make methods easily distinguishable from properties, so I would do this:

```vb
Dim str = obj.ToString()
```

rather than this:

```vb
Dim str = obj.ToString
```

With constructors though, there's little risk of mistaking them for properties but there is some risk of mistaking them for arrays, e.g.

```vb
Dim tables As DataTable()
```

Declares a variable of type `DataTable` array without creating an object while this:

```vb
Dim table As New DataTable()
```

declares a variable of type `DataTable` and assigns a new object to it. In my opinion, omitting the parentheses on constructors reduces the likelihood of confusion while including it on other methods does the same.